# Micrometer registering Counter each time update is needed

Tags: java, prometheus, micrometer

From my app I need report to Prometheus , via Micrometer, a Counter metric named "foo".

Metric have multiple tags, so eventually metric will reported dozens of times per minute with different tags.

Do I need to create a counter via  `Counter.builder` , registering it in `MeterRegistry` and saving the reference of it in map, or it's fine just registering each time value is updated without keeping the reference to it?

```
public void reportCounter(String tag1,String tag2,String tag3, int value){

    Counter.builder("foo")
                .tag("tag1",tag1)
                .tag("tag2",tag2)
                .tag("tag3",tag3)
                .register(meterRegistry).increment(count);
}
```

will it cause issues with performance?

As I wrote before I   have many counters, no reason to keep reference to them.

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on using the `register(...)` method each time without keeping a reference in your code since it is guaranteed to only create one counter for the same combination of name and tags.

However, be careful if your tags has a very large unique combinations since this will be added to a map in the micrometer library.

From the javadocs:

> Add the counter to a single registry, or return an existing counter in that registry. The returned counter will be unique for each registry, but each registry is guaranteed to only create one counter for the same combination of name and tags.

[Reference](https://javadoc.io/static/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.12.0/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Counter.Builder.html#register(io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry))

Comment: fyi: we added a feature in 1.12 that can spare you even recreating the builder: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/4097
Also, if you want to learn more about high cardinality: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/